# Connect to multiple local sites on mobile

Tags: mobile, xampp, virtualhost

I have multiple local sites which I develop on my local machine.

I'd like to be able to access them on a mobile device while they are still local on my machine.

Using `XAMPP` these are example `vhosts` configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/design and photos/agency1/website/public_html"
    ServerName agency1dev.com
    <Directory "C:/design and photos/agency1/website/public_html">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted         
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/design and photos/captives/website/public_html"
    ServerName capdev.com
    <Directory "C:/design and photos/captives/website/public_html">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted         
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Windows hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    agency1dev.com
127.0.0.1    capdev.com
```

I understand I can use my machines IP address to reach e.g.:

```
http://196.168.2.3:8080
```

But this goes to the `XAMPP` dir, so, how do I access e.g. `agency1dev.com`?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Finch, https://meetfinch.com

It's very easy to use (recently released a GUI for it) and just 'works' without having to do anything.

Full disclosure: I'm involved in the project.

Comment: Thanks, I had heard of this but couldn't remember the name and it didn't appear in any relevant searches

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was using [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/)

Very easy to implement:

```
In cmd or some shell

Go to: C:\path\to\ngrok

Type:

ngrok http -host-header=myapp.dev 8080

Change myapp.dev to suit what you want to look at - and change port (8080) accordingly

Then look at output and it will give you a http and https url to navigate to on your device

Simple!
```